# Reading from multiple databases in a single job - hadoop

Tags: database, jdbc, hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new to Hadoop. I am trying to write a map-reduce job that reads data from two different databses (say MySQL and Postgres). I know that we can read from a single database, for example MySQL, using the DBInputFormat, and by specifying the JDBC driver as follows:

```
DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf, “com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”, “jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase”);
```

However, how can we do that if we want to read from multiple databases? in other words, how can we specify multiple JDBC drivers in the DBConfiguration?

Comment: Thank you a lot guys. I am aware of Sqoop and other techniques to import the data into HDFS, but I do not want to do that. I would rather to read the data directly from those SQL databases and then perform my analysis on it. I do not want to migrate any data into my HDFS. 

Has anyone of you heard of HIHO? Do you think it is a good idea to use it in my case? would it be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to `MultipleInputs` would be to run 2 map only jobs, then a final job to use the output from those jobs as input (with an identity mapper) and perform any merge logic you require in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no OOB support for this. As an alternative you could export data from your RDBMSs as raw text files and then use [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) to do whatever you want.

I would also suggest you to have a look at [Apache sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org), in case you haven't done yet.